# Отсутствует подключение archive.php

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день! Такой вопрос: написал свою тему Wordpress. Смотрю на нее - не нарадуюсь, но почему то архивы рубрик и меток строятся не по файлу archive.php, а по index.php. При этом на локальном хостинге все работает нормально. Других шаблонов - вроде category.php или tag.php нет.  При этом когда переименовал archive.php в category.php все заработало, но это же не дело. Постоянные ссылки обновлял, тему переставлял, на новых рубриках пробовал - безрезультатно.  Ума не приложу в чем причина. Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Код archive.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Страница Архивов по меткам, категориям, датам и автору
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="site-content">

    <div id="main" class="archive-page">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <header class="page-header">

        <?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
        the_archive_description( '<div class="archive-description">', '</div>' );?>

    </header><!-- .page-header -->

    <ul class="archive-featured">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $postcounter++; ?>

        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

            <div class="blog-post-image">   
                 <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'itemprop' => 'image' ) ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="blogwrap">

                <?php if ( is_category()  ) { ?>
                    <div class="entry-tag"><?php the_tags('',' '); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php  if ( is_tag() ||  is_author() || is_date() ) { ?>
                    <div class="entry-category" itemprop="articleSection"><?php the_category(' '); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>

                <div class="entry-meta">

                    <span itemprop="author"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span>
                    <span itemprop="datePublished"><?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' назад';?></span>

                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

                <div class="entry-content" itemprop="articleBody">

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            </div>

        </li><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

        <?php if ($postcounter % 5 == 0) : ?><li class="archive-advert"><?php echo get_option( 'pb_archive_advert' );?></li><?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile;

        the_posts_navigation();

        endif; ?>

    </ul>

</div><!-- #main -->
```

Comment: Если на локальном все нормально, а на внешнем хостинге - не работает, то проблема в переносе. Как переносили?

Comment: Заархивировал папку и перенес, на  хостинге установил. База данных не нужна же, просто тема. Установил через админку

Comment: А базу??? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220

Comment: База зачем? Мне только тема нужна

Comment: Если сайт перенес неправильно, на нем могут возникать любые ошибки. Почитайте, в общем, по ссылке.

Comment: Сам сайт то не переносил. Просто тему. И ошибок то нету, абсолютных путей не прописано, и когда category.php назвал файл работает архив как надо...

Comment: О. На хостинге был сайт, где был установлен плагин Onion Buzz. Это он виноват, правда не знаю в чем его вина конкретно.

Answer (score 0):

Плагин Onion Buzz был виноват. Он создает собственные термы и таксономии и типы постов, каким то образом это повлияло на работу архивов